# Obfuscate VS.Net 2017 / WPF / ClickOnce / multiple assembly app

Tags: .net, wpf, deployment, clickonce, obfuscation

I have a VS2017 / C# / WPF app that needs to be deployed with ClickOnce. The files that need protection are the main .exe and a .dll that supports it. Ive tried:
ConfuserEx - makes my .exe crash right upon load.
Dotfuscator (I am willing to pay for a good tool) - Left the .dll totally  readable (in decompiler)

Best practices?
Other suggestions?

Comment: Talk to presale guys of the commercial products, or ping the developers of the free ones. Stack Overflow is not for "how to".

Comment: I have a similar situation with WPF and CodeGenHero.  I recently learned about "Eazfuscator.NET", but cannot attest to how well it works yet, but if you give it a try let me know!  https://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net

Comment: Dotfuscator has support for ClickOnce, and if you download an Evaluation version, you get access to the support team, who can help you figure out any issues you are having. Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions (we make Dotfuscator).